# Cannot interpret a BASIC file querying SQL

Tags: sql, vba, basic

So, I am trying to figure out where the `TOTAL_CHG` is coming from. Below is a snippet of where it is first used (not defined at all before).

```
...
 sStrBalance = " (TOTAL_CHG - (ISNULL((SELECT SUM(isnull(t.amount, 0)) FROM transactions t " & _
        " WHERE     cp.contpolid = t.contpolid AND t.tran_date <= '" & GRepdate & "'), 0) + " & _
        " ISNULL((SELECT SUM(isnull(dirpayamt, 0))  FROM  bkrtrans bkr " & _
        " WHERE     cp.contpolid = bkr.contpolid), 0))) "
...
```

And then the next block of code that references it again is as follows:

```
...
    strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & " SELECT  cp.Contpolid, cp.CTYPE_ID, cp.C#, cp.REV, " & _
                vbCrLf & "CASE WHEN cp.Div_Code = 'GM' THEN 'SLP' ELSE 'SCA' END, " & _
                vbCrLf & "cp.Effective_ as EFFDATE, ADJUSTMENT, cp.terminatio, cp.TOTAL_CHG, " & _
                vbCrLf & " ISNULL((SELECT     SUM(isnull(t.amount, 0)) FROM transactions t " & _
                vbCrLf & " WHERE     cp.contpolid = t.contpolid AND t.tran_date <= '" & GRepdate & "'), 0) AS Payments, " & _
                vbCrLf & " ISNULL((SELECT     SUM(isnull(dirpayamt, 0)) FROM  bkrtrans bkr " & _
                vbCrLf & " WHERE     cp.contpolid = bkr.contpolid), 0) AS BrkPayment,  " & _
                 sStrBalance & " AS Balance, cast(0 as numeric(12,2)) as SixtyDays, cast(0 as numeric(12,2)) as NinetyDays , " & _
                vbCrLf & "  cast(0 as numeric(12,2)) as OverNinetyDays , CASE WHEN Register_D IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE CASE WHEN Register_D < '" & GRepdate & "' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END END "
            strSQL = strSQL & vbCrLf & " FROM CONTRACTS_POLICIES cp (NOLOCK) /*JOIN Salesmen s (NOLOCK) ON s.salesmenid = cp.sales1*/ " & _
                vbCrLf & " Where cp.CTYPE_ID = 1 And cp.Cancel_dat Is Null and CP.Sales1 is Not NULL " & _
                vbCrLf & " AND ((CP.Effective_ <= '" & GRepdate & "' AND CP.Rev = 0) OR (CP.Adjustment <= '" & GRepdate & "' AND CP.Rev > 0)) " & _
                vbCrLf & " AND NOT((" & sStrBalance & " > 0 AND cp.Effective_ <= '01/01/1996') OR (" & sStrBalance & "< 0 AND cp.Effective_ <= '01/01/1998')) " & _
                vbCrLf & " And " & sStrBalance & " <> 0  "
...
```

What table is it even coming from? It seems like it is defined in the first block of code but isn't really a value yet.

Comment: It is presumably the same as cp.TOTAL_CHG  just without the qualifier where cp is an alias for CONTRACTS_POLICIES.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out! Thank you =]. Want to post the answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Repeat after me: always preprend the alias to all columns when using joins. Repeat after me. The developer that comes after you will thank you.

Comment: Especially when us Millennials have to come back and mess with it. Pft...